# How do I automatically add new files to Git?

Tags: git, github

I know I can just do git add for all the files, but I got a ton of files. Is there a way to do something like "git add *.h", or "git add *.py" ?

Comment: "git add ." should do it

Comment: Note that `git add .` will add everything not in `.gitignore`.

Comment: You mean people run git an do not use .gitignore? i am devastated! ;-) Of course to me the puzzle is why Hisoka, as he seemed to have a good idea what he should do, did not set up a test git repo and try his own suggestion? But there you go.

Comment: Actually this probably part of a bigger problem. I did "git add ." and then "git commit -a" in the same directory. But when I do git push, it says: fatal: No destination configured to push to.

Comment: @yoda, @PurplePilot: Or maybe the files are in subdirectories.

Comment: @Hisoka: This problem isn't part of that problem; they're completely separate. That error means exactly what it says. What remote repository are you trying to push to? Github, apparently. Your repository doesn't know that. You need to do something along the lines of `git remote add origin git@github.com:hisoka/myrepository.git`, assuming it's set up in github.

Comment: Also, part of github's most basic tutorial: http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can say `git add *.py` 
Make sure you have done git init before doing this.

To add all files in a folder you can simply say `git add .`

Comment: You can quote it like `git add '*.py'`, and git will add all matching files in subdirectories.

Comment: Actually this probably part of a bigger problem. I did "git add ." and then "git commit -a" in the same directory. But when I do git push, it says: fatal: No destination configured to push to.

Answer (score 6):

When you are using something like `*.py`, you have to understand that the shell is doing the extension and not git. It won't consider subdirectories for the extension, and also, you end up adding ignored files, which is something you  probably don't want ( `git add` by default doesn't add ignored files, unless the file is explicitly specified, which is the case when shell extension happens)

What you can do is something like below:

```
git add /\*.py
```

The asterisk * is quoted from the shell in this and will include the files from subdirectories. And you won't end up adding ignored files as well.

It is frowned upon to do `git add .` - you don't know exactly what you end up adding. I wouldn't recommend doing it.

As for your other problem while pushing, first you have to have a proper remote setup:

```
git remote add origin yourremoterepourl
```

Answer (score 3):

`git add .` will add all the files - new and edited, in the current directory and sub-directories recursively. Note that `.`can be replaced by any directory in the current `git` repo.