# Automatically add repos to github?

Tags: git, netbeans, github

So I set up my GitHub to format my Netbeans projects to look good and exclude files I don't want. The only problem I am running into is actually creating the Repos. Say I make a new Project in Netbeans, I want this project to automatically be added to my GitHub as a new Repo, instead of manually creating each repo. Is this possible?

Comment: > Here you go 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456032/how-to-setup-github-repository-in-my-netbeans-ide
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642126/how-do-i-automatically-add-new-files-to-git

Comment: I am not sure about the first one, but the second one adds all current files. I would like to push all new netbeans projects to github automatically. So when I create a project, it gets added to github, when I delete one, it gets removed from github.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like customizing Netbeans I'm sure you could use the GitHub API to do exactly what you've described.  For example, the GitHub v3 API has a call for creating a new repo:

http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create

You can also delete repositories.

You would need to use the `git` command to actually commit the files and keep the repo up-to-date.

Sounds like a fun project!